# Class destructors and pointer deallocation

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, destructor

I am writing a class (virtual_flight_runtime_environment), and it is mostly non-static, with the exception of one static function for the purposes of a Win32 thread using it as its function. The class declares struct simaircraftdata* aircraftdata (a data struct), and calls 'aircraftdata = new aircraftdata;' in the constuctor (public: virtual_flight_runtime_environment()).

My question is about destructors and memory deallocation. I have written the destructor as such:

```
    ~virtual_flight_runtime_environment(void) {
         /*..Other code, i.e. closing win32 handles, etc.*/
        delete aircraftdata;
    }
```

Now, the class is declared in another function (the DoWork function of a .Net background worker) like so:

```
    virtual_flight_runtime_environment* this_environment = new virtual_flight_runtime_environment;
```

And just before the end of the function, I call 'delete this_environment;'. Immediately after, 'this_environment' would have gone out of scope, and the  desturctor should have been called.

Is this correct? I do notice continued increases in memory usage over time, and I'm wondering if I've done something wrong. Does calling delete on a pointer just make it a null pointer, or does it deallocate the data at the end of it?

Any advice would be appreciated,

Collin Biedenkapp

Comment: If `virtual_flight_runtime_environment`'s constructor creates an `aircraftdata` object and the destructor destroys it, the lifetime of the `aircraftdata` object is the same as the lifetime of the `virtual_flight_runtime_environment` object. Typically that means a contained object, not a pointer and an allocated object. Is there a reason that the `aircraft data` object has to be separately allocated?

Comment: Calling `delete` frees (deallocates) the memory indicated by the pointer. `delete` does not set the pointer to `NULL`, it still points at same area of memory that is no longer "valid". Some ppl use macros for this: `#define SAFE_DELETE(p) {delete p; p=NULL;}`

Comment: @Agent_L: A better name for that macro might be `DELETE_AND_HIDE_LOGIC_ERRORS_WHILE_CREATING_AN_ILLUSION_OF_SAFETY`, perhaps shortened to `UNSAFE_DELETE`.

Comment: @Agent_L - there's no point in setting a member pointer to null in a destructor; after the destructor runs there's no object, so no pointer to look at.

Comment: It seems that you did not attempt to actually debug the program. The least you can do is to add some log messages in constructors and destructors so you can see if creations match destructions. eg in ctor : `printf("Object aircraftdata [%p] ctor", (void*) this);` and in dtor `printf("Object aircraftdata [%p] dtor", (void*) this);` `printf("Object aircraftdata [%p] created", (void*) this);`. You can use the raw value of `this` to identify which object is being investigated.

Comment: @PeteBecker - yes, ofc, no point in dtor. But he asked if pointers are nulled, so he probably uses them in other places too.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - I have no idea what logic errors you're talking about. This macro is only for remembering what was deleted and what was not. I did not choose the name.

Comment: @Agent_L - I hadn't noticed the question about nulling the pointer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I just found that Stroustrup said it is **recommended** for compilers to null a pointer after delete. Noone does, so macro/template is your next best thing. (I personally had never written bare delete in my life.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct connection between a delete in your program and whether it will directly be visible in say the task manager because the OS tries to optimize memory utilization. When you look in the task manager you will typically see the working set  size of your application, this is a measure of how much memory your app has requested but not necessarily how much it is currently using.

And to your question, yes deleting the memory as you did it is the WTG although as others have pointed out using smart pointers is generally much better to handle memory to avoid later headaches.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost correct.

`delete this_environment` calls the destructor of `virtual_flight_runtime_environment`. The destructor executes `delete aircraftdata`.

Right after that, the memory occupied by the instance of `virtual_flight_runtime_environment` is released.

Please be aware that `delete` statement doesn't set the pointer to `NULL`.

So I see no problem in your code given the information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct.
Calling delete on your this_environment will cause the destructor of that class to be called before it's memory is deallocated. The destructor deletes the aircraft data. Looks correct.

You might consider instead of having a member variable containing a raw pointer to  *aircraftdata* instead using an **auto_ptr** or in c++11 **unique_ptr** which will ensure that it gets deleted automatically when it's containing class is constructed. Look it up, this isn't the place to teach it and it's just a suggestion, not a necessity.

Edit: And I also agree with Pete Becker's comment on the question, which is to question if this needs a pointer at all.

Comment: First, thanks for the advice everyone! Second, I've gotten in the habit of always putting large variables or structs on the heap, as apposed to the stack. Is it better or worse to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed explicitely call "delete this_environment". Otherwise, it's only the pointer itself (which exists on the stack) which would be destroyed. The data pointed, on the heap, would still exist.

The other solution is to simply get rid of the pointer and declare your variable as such :

```
virtual_flight_runtime_environment this_environment;
```

That way, your object will directly exist on the stack, and its lifetime will depend on the scope in which it is declared - and the destructor will be automatically called at this point, calling in turn the delete for your internal data.